# Call and wait for an observable based on each item of an array and return the array

Tags: rxjs, observable

I want to display a list of messages contains in a chat with all information related to each message (particularly the author name of each message).
So I have the following function that returns an Observable of an array of messages:

```
getLastMessagesOfEvent(eventId: string, limitTo?: number): Observable<any> {
    console.log('MessageService#getLastMessagesOfEvent - Event ID: eventId');
    let chatIdPath = `/${this.authService.getCurrentUserCompany()}/events/${eventId}/chat`;
    return this.af.object(chatIdPath)
            .mergeMap(chat => {
              let chatId = chat.$value
              console.log('chatId ', chatId);
              let chatPath = `/${this.authService.getCurrentUserCompany()}/eventChats/${chatId}/messages`;
              let query: any = {};
              query.orderByChild = 'timestamp';
              if (limitTo) query.limitToLast = limitTo;
              return this.af.list(chatPath, {query: query});
            })
}
```

A message contains a `content` and an `author_uid`.

Before returning the array of messages I would like, for each message, to retrieve the author info first (based on `author_uid` and through I function called for instance `getUserInfo(author_uid): Observable<any>`).

So in the end I would like to return an array of messages and for each message have a `content` and an `author_info`.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `this.af.list` returns an Observable emitting an array of results you could write:

```
this.af.object(chatIdPath)
  .mergeMap(chat => {...})
  .mergeMap(messages => Observable.forkJoin(
    messages.map(m => getUserInfo(m.author_uid)
      .map(additionalInfo => {
        m.additionalInfo = additionalInfo;
        return m;
      })
    )
  ))
  .subscribe(messages => console.log(messages))
```

For obvious reasons I didn't test it but you should get the point.

The `messages.map()` expression returns an array of Observables where `forkJoin` subscribes to all of them. Then each inner Observable maps the `additionalInfo` into the original `m`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out `forkJoin` which will run multiple observables in parallel and emit the latest result from each.

```
Observable.forkJoin(
   Observable.of("Hello"),
   Observable.of("World")
).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res[0], res[1]) 
})
```